# Retrieving text data from <content:encoded> in XML file

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, scrapy, xml-parsing

I have an XML file which looks like this:

```
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:excerpt="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/excerpt/"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:wp="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/"
>

<channel>

<item>
        <title>Label: some_title&quot;</title>
        <link>some_link</link>
        <pubDate>some_date</pubDate>
        <dc:creator><![CDATA[University]]></dc:creator>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">https://link.link</guid>
        <description></description>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[[vc_row][vc_column][vc_column_text]<strong>some text<a href="https://link.link" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">text</a> some more text</strong><!--more-->

[caption id="attachment_344" align="aligncenter" width="524"]<img class="-image-" src="link.link.png" alt="" width="524" height="316" /> <em>A <a href="link.link" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">screenshot</a> by the people</em>[/caption]

&nbsp;

<strong>some more text</strong>

&nbsp;
<div class="entry-content">

<em>Leave your comments</em>

</div>
<div class="post-meta wf-mobile-collapsed">
<div class="entry-meta"></div>
</div>
[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column][dt_quote]<strong><b>RESEARCH | ARTICLE </b></strong>University[/dt_quote][/vc_column][/vc_row]]]></content:encoded>
        <excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[]]></excerpt:encoded>
</item>
some more <item> </item>s here
</channel>
```

I want to extract the raw text within the `<content:encoded>` section, excluding the tags and urls. I have tried this with BeautifulSoup, and Scarpy, as well as other lxml methods. Most return an empty list.

Is there a way for me to retrieve this information without having to use regex?

Much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I opened the XML file using:

```
content = []
with open(xml_file, "r") as file:
    content = file.readlines()
    content = "".join(content)
    xml = bs(content, "lxml")
```

then I tried this with scrapy:

```
response = HtmlResponse(url=xml_file, encoding='utf-8')

response.selector.register_namespace('content', 
                                     'http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/')
response.xpath('channel/item/content:encoded').getall()
```

which returns an empty list.

and tried the code in the first answer:

```
soup = bs(xml.select_one("content:encoded").text, "html.parser")
text = "\n".join(
    s.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ") for s in soup.select("strong"))
print(text)
```

and get this error: `Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.`

When I opened the file with lxml, I ran this for loop:

```
data = {}
n = 0

for item in xml.findall('item'):
  id = 'claim_id_' + str(n)
  keys = {}
  title = item.find('title').text
  keys['label'] = title.split(': ')[0]
  keys['claim'] = title.split(': ')[1]
  if item.find('content:encoded'):
    keys['text'] = bs(html.unescape(item.encoded.text), 'lxml')
  data[id] = keys
  print(data)
  n += 1
```

It saved the label and claim perfectly well, but nothing for the text. Now that I opened the file using BeautifulSoup, it returns this error: `'NoneType' object is not callable`

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include some example code you where you used BeautifulSoup or Scrapy to make it easier for people to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually got the text part using regular expressions (regex).

```
import re

for item in root.iter('item'):
  grandchildren = item.getchildren()
  for grandchild in grandchildren:
    if 'encoded' in grandchild.tag:
      text = grandchild.text
      text = re.sub(r'\[.*?\]', "", text)   # gets rid of square brackets and their content
      text = re.sub(r'\<.*?\>', "", text)   # gets rid of <> signs and their content
      text = text.replace("&nbsp;", "")   # gets rid of &nbsp;
      text = " ".join(text.split())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need text inside `<strong>` tags, you can use my example. Otherwise, only regex seems suitable here:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml_doc = """
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:excerpt="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/excerpt/"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:wp="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/"
>

...the XML from the question...

</rss>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_doc, "xml")

soup = BeautifulSoup(soup.select_one("content|encoded").text, "html.parser")

text = "\n".join(
    s.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ") for s in soup.select("strong")
)
print(text)
```

Prints:

```
some text text some more text
some more text
RESEARCH | ARTICLE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Andrej. There are many items in the xml file. So, I'm iterating over them in a for loop `for item in root.findall('channel/item')`. Then I run `soup = BeautifulSoup(item, "xml")`, but that gives me an `expected string or bytes-like object` error. Can you help with that please?

Comment: @MoeB You probably mix `lxml` and `beautifulsoup` together. I recommend to load all XML with `beautifulsoup` and skip `lxml` step.

Comment: I added parts of my code in. Can you see where the problem is?